# Convert Javascript object to Date object

Tags: javascript

I have object which contains this kind of information:

```
{"birthdayDay": 17, "birthdayMonth": 7, "birthdayYear": 2021}
```

And I want to convert it to something like this `1988-03-01T00:00:00.000Z` with the most efficient way. Any suggestions please?

Any suggestions?

Comment: The way this works, is that you post your attempt, and show what the issue is with it.

Comment: const temp = {"birthdayDay": 17, "birthdayMonth": 7, "birthdayYear": 2021};
const tempDate = new Date(temp.birthdayYear, temp.birthdayMonth, temp.birthdayDay);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const data = {'birthdayDay': 17, 'birthdayMonth': 7, 'birthdayYear': 2021}

const date = new Date(data.birthdayYear, data.birthdayMonth, data.birthdayDay)

console.log(date.toISOString())
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var data = {"birthdayDay": 17, "birthdayMonth": 7, "birthdayYear": 2021};

var date_obj = new Date(data.birthdayYear, data.birthdayMonth, data.birthdayDay).toISOString();

console.log(date_obj);
```

Comment: It should be var date_obj = new Date(data.birthdayYear, data.birthdayMonth, data.birthdayDay).toISOString() to get desired output.

Comment: @MohammadAslam, that depends. The OP asked to convert to a `Date` *object* (see title).